# Issue with Combine function in Apache Beam Go sdk

Tags: apache-beam, spring-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

We came across an issue with the Combine operation with Apache Beam Go SDK (v2.28.0), when running a pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow. I understand that the Go SDK is experimental but it would be great if someone can help us understand if there’s anything wrong with our code, or if there's a bug in the Go SDK or Dataflow. The issue only happens when running the pipeline with Google Dataflow, with some large data set. We are trying to combine a `PCollection<pairedVec>`, with

```
type pairedVec struct {
    Vec1 [1048576]uint64
    Vec2 [1048576]uint64
}
```

There are 10,000,000 items in the PCollection.

Main func:

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    beam.Init()
    ctx := context.Background()
    pipeline := beam.NewPipeline()
    scope := pipeline.Root()

    records := textio.ReadSdf(scope, *inputFile)
    rRecords := beam.Reshuffle(scope, records)

    vecs := beam.ParDo(scope, &genVecFn{LogN: *logN}, rRecords)
    histogram := beam.Combine(scope, &combineVecFn{LogN: *logN}, vecs)

    lines := beam.ParDo(scope, &flattenVecFn{}, histogram)
    textio.Write(scope, *outputFile, lines)

    if err := beamx.Run(ctx, pipeline); err != nil {
        log.Exitf(ctx, "Failed to execute job: %s", err)
    }
}
```

After reading the input file, Dataflow scheduled 1000 workers to generate the PCollection, and started to do the combination. Then the worker number reduced to almost 1 and lasted for a very long time. Eventually the job failed with the following error log:

```
2021-03-02T06:13:40.438112597ZWorkflow failed. Causes: S09:CombinePerKey/CoGBK'1/Read+CombinePerKey/main.combineVecFn+CombinePerKey/main.combineVecFn/Extract+beam.dropKeyFn+main.flattenVecFn+textio.Write/beam.addFixedKeyFn+textio.Write/CoGBK/Write failed., The job failed because a work item has failed 4 times. Look in previous log entries for the cause of each one of the 4 failures. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors. The work item was attempted on these workers: go-job-1-1614659244459204-03012027-u5s6-harness-q8tx Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service., go-job-1-1614659244459204-03012027-u5s6-harness-44hk Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service., go-job-1-1614659244459204-03012027-u5s6-harness-05nm Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service., go-job-1-1614659244459204-03012027-u5s6-harness-l22w Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.
```

[The change of worker number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ80E.png)

**Edit**

Tried to add a step to "pre-combine" the records to 100,000 keys (combineDomain=100000) before combining all of them together:

Main function:

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    beam.Init()
    ctx := context.Background()
    pipeline := beam.NewPipeline()
    scope := pipeline.Root()

    records := textio.ReadSdf(scope, *inputFile)
    rRecords := beam.Reshuffle(scope, records)

    vecs := beam.ParDo(scope, &genVecFn{LogN: *logN}, rRecords)

    keyVecs := beam.ParDo(scope, &addRandomKeyFn{Domain: *combineDomain}, vecs)
    combinedKeyVecs := beam.CombinePerKey(scope, &combineVecFn{LogN: *logN}, keyVecs)
    combinedVecs := beam.DropKey(scope, combinedKeyVecs)

    histogram := beam.Combine(scope, &combineVecFn{LogN: *logN}, combinedVecs)

    lines := beam.ParDo(scope, &flattenVecFn{}, histogram)
    textio.Write(scope, *outputFile, lines)

    if err := beamx.Run(ctx, pipeline); err != nil {
        log.Exitf(ctx, "Failed to execute job: %s", err)
    }
}
```

But the job scheduled only one worker for it, and failed after a long time:

```
Workflow failed. Causes: S06:Reshuffle/e6_gbk/Read+Reshuffle/e6_gbk/GroupByWindow+Reshuffle/e6_unreify+main.genVecFn+main.addRandomKeyFn+CombinePerKey/CoGBK'2+CombinePerKey/main.combineVecFn/Partial+CombinePerKey/CoGBK'2/Write failed., The job failed because a work item has failed 4 times. Look in previous log entries for the cause of each one of the 4 failures. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors. The work item was attempted on these workers: 
  go-job-1-1615178257414007-03072037-mrlo-harness-ppjj
      Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.,
  go-job-1-1615178257414007-03072037-mrlo-harness-czng
      Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.,
  go-job-1-1615178257414007-03072037-mrlo-harness-79n8
      Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.,
  go-job-1-1615178257414007-03072037-mrlo-harness-mj6c
      Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.
```

After adding another reshuffle before CombinePerKey(), the pipeline scheduled 1000 workers to process it. But the job was extremely slow, and uses a large amount of shuffle data. 1 hour later, genVecFn finished less than 10 percent, and had 8.08TB shuffle data. This is basically consistent with our production code, which eventually failed because it used up the 40TB shuffle data quota.

We tried another method to reduce workload on a single worker: segment the vector [1048576]uint64 into 32 pieces of [32768]uint64, and combine each of the pieces. Something like:

```
    totalLength := uint64(1 << *logN)
    segLength := uint64(1 << *segmentBits)
    for i := uint64(0); i < totalLength/segLength; i++ {
        fileName := strings.ReplaceAll(*outputFile, path.Ext(*outputFile), fmt.Sprintf("-%d-%d%s", i+1, totalLength/segLength, path.Ext(*outputFile)))
        pHistogram := beam.Combine(scope, &combineVecRangeFn{StartIndex: i * segLength, Length: segLength}, vecs)
        flattened := beam.ParDo(scope, &flattenVecRangeFn{StartIndex: i * segLength}, pHistogram)
        textio.Write(scope, fileName, flattened)
    }
```

The job succeeded eventually.

Comment: Source code: https://github.com/le0000000/dataflow_combine.git

Comment: I'm leaving an answer already, but I suggest adding a snippet of your code to the question itself in addition to linking to a repository. The pipeline code in main() is particularly useful to include in questions.

Comment: The crash happens because each element is ~17 Megabytes at best, meaning you have ~150+ Terabytes in total, overwhelming and crashing the machine.
Further, *at present* the Go SDK is using JSON as the coder, inflating the encoded values dramatically. (This is changing soon using Beam Schemas for a default binary encoding)
You can use beam.RegisterCoder to register a better coder for a given type, though you'll need to write/read the encodings yourself.

Comment: Oh, I'm a bit off, since I forgot about combiner lifting. I guess I'm a little surprised, as while there are *that* many elements contributing to the final result, everything gets combined to a single result per bundle due to combiner lifting.  However, if the end result is even 100GB for the final combine, that stage will take a small eternity to read through without any intermediate merges that the optimization can provide.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Daniel! I've included the main() function in the description.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Robert! What is the combiner lifting? Do you know any documents that I can learn from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your pipeline code, the job downsizing to 1 worker is behaving as expected for the Go SDK since it lacks some of the optimizations of the Java and Python SDKs. The reason it happens is because you use [`beam.Combine`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.Globally.html) which is a global combine, meaning that every element in the PCollection is combined down to one value. On the Go SDK this means that all elements need to be localized to a single worker to be combined, which for 10 million items each of which is about 16 megabytes, takes too long and the job most likely times out (you can probably confirm this by looking for a timeout message in the Dataflow logs).

Other SDKs have optimizations in place which split the input elements among workers to combine down, before consolidating to a single worker. For example in the [Java SDK](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.Globally.html): "Combining can happen in parallel, with different subsets of the input PCollection being combined separately, and their intermediate results combined further, in an arbitrary tree reduction pattern, until a single result value is produced."

Fortunately, this solution is easily to implement manually for the Go SDK. Simply place your elements into N buckets (where N is greater than the number of workers you'd ideally want) by assigning random keys in the range of [0, N). Then perform a [`CombinePerKey`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam#CombinePerKey) and only elements with matching keys need to be localized on a worker, allowing this Combine to be split in multiple workers. Then follow that up with [`DropKey`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam#DropKey) and then the global Combine, and you should get the intended result.

Comment: To add deep dive details to it, the root is that the Go SDK doesn't currently translate a beam.Combine into the combine_global URN, it just adds an ordinary AddFixedKey DoFn and does combine per key. Using the proper combine_global URN allows the runner (Dataflow) to know that it can do the optimization for you, rather than manually bucketing it yourselves.

I've outlined the current parts of the code that would need changing to fix this in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11928. Contributions welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and suggestion Daniel! As I updated in the description (the "Edit" session). I tried to combine the pcollection to 100,000 keys first, but the job failed with another error. I also tried to combine to 10,000 keys, and the job failed with the same error.

Comment: It's strange that it's still only using one worker. Are you on a free trial account? Free trials have a limit to the number of CPUs available, so the job may not be able to autoscale. If not, then maybe adding a Reshuffle just before the CombinePerKey might help? (That one seems unlikely to me, but it's easy to try)

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Unfortunately adding another reshuffle did not help. 1000 workers were used for generating the vectors, but the job was extremely slow and used a ton of shuffle data. Like I updated in the description, I also tried this in our production code, and the job failed eventually for using too much shuffle data. Instead, I tried to segment the vectors and combine on the pieces. This worked for the inputs I mentioned, but I'm not sure if it is scalable for even larger inputs.